# Azure STT sdk not working in AWS Lambda (returning Reason.Canceled immediately)

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, speech-to-text

Azure STT Python SDK returns "Reason.Cancelled" automatically after starting the transcription.
I am using it in AWS Lambda environment.

Here is the response:

> SpeechRecognitionCanceledEventArgs(session_id=e7fdaf10597049d0aea4fbf17840421d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=087f2227ea124b64839e2efc1fc37719, text="", reason=ResultReason.Canceled))

Here is my code:

```
def speech_recognize_continuous_from_file():
        results = []
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        """performs continuous speech recognition with input from an audio file"""
        # <SpeechContinuousRecognitionWithFile>
        speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
        # Ask for detailed recognition result
        speech_config.output_format = speechsdk.OutputFormat.Detailed

        # If you also want word-level timing in the detailed recognition results, set the following.
        # Note that if you set the following, you can omit the previous line
        #   "speech_config.output_format = speechsdk.OutputFormat.Detailed",
        # since word-level timing implies detailed recognition results.
        speech_config.request_word_level_timestamps()
        audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=file_name)

        speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

        def new_func(evt):

            results.append(json.loads(evt.result.json))


        #CustomPhrases = ["villusectomy", "Villa","abranchi","ataabranchi","ateabrasio"]
        CustomPhrases = event["CustomPhrases"]

        phrase_list_grammar = speechsdk.PhraseListGrammar.from_recognizer(speech_recognizer)

        for phr in CustomPhrases:
            phrase_list_grammar.addPhrase(phr)

       
        done = False

        def stop_cb(evt: speechsdk.SessionEventArgs):
            print(evt)

            nonlocal done
            done = True

        # Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer

        speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: new_func(evt))

        # stop continuous recognition on either session stopped or canceled events
        speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
        speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

        # Start continuous speech recognition
        speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
        while not done:
            
            time.sleep(.5)
            


        speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
        # </SpeechContinuousRecognitionWithFile>

        phrase_list_grammar.clear()

        print(datetime.datetime.now())

        return results
```

I expected to get transcription immediately.